# How to pass a variable from .cs to .aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, data-transfer

As the title suggests, I want to add something to a table (inside aspx page) depending on some infos I get from a database (so if I have an item x in db I will make a bool type variable in cs).

My question is, is there any method to send that bool to aspx so I can use it inside an if statement (in order to add the respective columns to my table).

Comment: There are several ways how this could be achieved and this is VERY basic stuff. Maybe you should read up a little more on ASP.NET / WebForms and/or do some tutorials to get a better understanding of how it works...

Comment: I managed to do it, and sorry for not reading but i needed to get it done fast...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need a `session` variable here, you can simply declare a class level property and use it in your ASPX page:-

```
public bool variable { get; set; }
```

and then directly use it in your aspx page:-

```
<%=variable %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store the value of bool in session and display it in aspx, something like that

```
bool val;
// Your code
Session["value"] = val;
```

and use it in aspx such as

```
<%= Session["value"]%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a div and make your own HTML code in the .cs code behind file.
Or, you could simply use some labels and give information like that.

html:

```
<div>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><asp:Label id="somelabel" runat="server" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

.cs

```
somelabel.Text = "yourdata";
```

Or you could add all your html code to a single string. Then, if your div is called `divTable`:

```
divTable.InnerHtml = liststring;
```

An example:

```
        liststring = liststring + 
       "<img src=" + SQLdata.Tables[0].Rows[x]["imageSource"].ToString() + 
       "<ul style='list-style-type: none;'>" +
       "<li>" + SQLdata.Tables[0].Rows[x]["Name"].ToString() + "</li>" +
       "<li><b>Adress: </b>" + SQLdata.Tables[0].Rows[x]["Adress"].ToString() + "</li>" +
       "<li><b>Website: </b><a href='http://" + SQLdata.Tables[0].Rows[x]["Website"].ToString() + "'>" + SQLdata.Tables[0].Rows[x]["Website"].ToString() + "</a></li>" + "</ul></div>";
divTable.InnerHtml = liststring;
```

Ofcourse you have to css a bit to get the correct display, but this will get you going I guess...

Comment: Creating HTML in the code-behind is BAD design IMO - Views are for HTML and code-behind for logic...

Comment: true, but I'm just giving him examples

Comment: The OP seems to be a beginner and so you should NOT give "bad examples" IMO, because the OP could take them as "the way to go" as he/she does not know better.

Comment: easy man, maybe I don't know any better and still try to help? pff. In fact, you are commenting on other's bad examples but do not care to post your own answer.. If he asks simple questions then he will get simple answers. Simple as that!

Comment: Didn't meant to offend you, sorry. We are all here to learn and its fine to try to help in any way you know, but feedback from others should also be valued and not disrespected. That doesn't mean what I say must be correct or "the best way", but in this case at least one other agrees with me. As already said SO is a community and we are all here to learn from each other - I myself often do so by other improving, correcting or commenting my answers...

Comment: `In fact, you are commenting on other's bad examples but do not care to post your own answer..` In fact I do care that the OP gets a good answer - and that can very well be the answer from someone else (I may can help to improve). With a good answer the OP AND the community gains knowledge and as a part of that community so do I.